# How to enter an array length?

Tags: java, arrays

I tried to enter the length of array using .length, but got mistake.
What is exactly wrong?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Storage {
public static int i = 0, size;
static int[] number;

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the value of array?");
    number = new int [input.nextInt()];
    System.out.println("Write the numbers:");

    for (int i : number) {
        number[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Array:");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(number));
}

}
```

And the output is:

```
What is the value of array?
3
Write the numbers:

1
2
3
Array:
[3, 0, 0]
```

Comment: `for (int i=0; i < number.length; ++i) { number[i] = input.nextInt(); }`

Comment: Did you tried `lengh` or `length` ?

Comment: both, but no result

Comment: we allowed to use just the for each loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not incrementing the index, so stores all the values you enter in the 0th index.Try this:

```
     for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
        number[i] = input.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Array:");

    for (int j : number) {
        System.out.println(j);
    }
```

Output:

```
What is the value of array?
3
Write the numbers:
1
2
3
Array:
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Foreach is used for reading values over a collection.

Use this instead.

```
for(int k = 0;k<numbers.length;k++)
{
    numbers[k] = input.nextInt();
}
```